# Adding to an existing object to make it reactive

Tags: vue.js

I have several rows of mysql data held in a vuex state, and this is the format

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "property_country": "usa",
    "property_name": "i and m towers",
    "property_stars": "4",
    "property_city": "austin",
    "property_region": "texas",
    "property_type": "serviced partment",
    "date_created": "3563763673",
    "date_updated": "33377363",
    "the_user_id": "1"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "property_country": "uk",
    "property_name": "eagle towers",
    "property_stars": "5",
    "property_city": "kampala",
    "property_region": "kampala",
    "property_type": "motel",
    "date_created": "3563763673",
    "date_updated": "33377363",
    "the_user_id": "1"
},
```

I am adding and getting back an object that i would like to add to the existing object

This is my mutation

```
CRUD_CREATE_PROPERTY: (state, response) => { 
    console.log(response.data); 
    state.properties.push(response.data)
    //Vue.set(state.properties, response.data.property.id, response.data);
},
```

according to the docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects on how to make the object reactive, this is the format

```
Vue.set(vm.someObject, 'b', 2)
```

I am returning a normal mysql row with data such as this

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "property_country": "canada",
    "property_name": "good motel",
    "property_stars": "4",
    "property_city": "montreal",
    "property_region": "montreal",
    "property_type": "camp",
    "date_created": "3563763673",
    "date_updated": "33377363",
    "the_user_id": "1"
}
```

How can i add the new row to make it appear in my template reactively?

Comment: Please expand on how exactly this not working for you, because [array `push`ing should be reactive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods); while `Vue.set` is meant for objects.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up puttting the part i wanted to be reactive into its own component and gave it a unique key.In my case it was a table and i aptly named my component `<Table />`and its not even a protected keyword to my surprise

```
<Table :key="componentKey" />
```

I then created this method

```
forceRerender() {
this.componentKey += 1;  
},
```

and accessed it when committing a mutation

```
.then( (response) => {
this.$store.commit('CRUD_CREATE_PROPERTY', response);
this.forceRerender();
})
```

also pay attention to the arrow function since `this` wouldn't work on old style javascript functions,since nowadays arrow function is now vanilla javascript.

i give credit to Michael Thiessen's article on Key-changing to force re-renders of a component which you can read here https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: As I said in my comment, you should not need to do this as Vuex [mutations follow Vue's reactivity rules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules).